# JUnit4 in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I'm trying to run some JUnit test units in Eclipse 3.5, but with no luck at all.

**JUnit3 works fine.**

When I create the JUnit4 Test unit, Eclipse offers to add the JUnit library to the class-path. I accept, but when I check to see if it was added in the project's properties panel, I can see JUnit4 was added, but no JARS where included.
If I choose **Edit**, the combo says "**JUnit 4**", and just below "**Current location: Not Found**".

When I launch a JUnit4 test, I get an error saying and **internal error occurred, NullPointerException**.

I've read for about two days now, and all references say eclipse INCLUDES JUnit4, but somehow, there seems to be something I'm missing.

I've tried re-creating my projects and creating a test in brand new ones with no luck.

```
package test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class AuthServiceTest {

    @Test
    public final void testValidateCredentials() {
        fail("Not yet implemented"); // TODO
    }

}
```

### [Edit]

I've added junit-4.8.1.jar to the project's classpath, and eclipse's classpath, but still the same problem.

### [Edit2]

I also added junit-dep-4.8.1.jar, since I'm not sure if these dependencies are necessary, but no change.

Comment: See also http://www.vogella.de/articles/JUnit/article.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the Eclipse 3.5 from Fedora's repository doesn't include JUnit, and installing the appropriate package didn't include it either.
Another Debian PC presented the same issue.  A clean download from eclipse.org solved the problem.

I *will* report this bug at some point :)

Answer (score 6):

Right click on the project name .

```
Built Path--> Add Libraries
```

Select the appropriate library from the list (JUnit 4 in this instance) .

Answer (score 1):

In my Eclipse installation JUnit 4 is provided, it's in plugins\org.junit4_4.3.1\junit.jar

If you can't find it, then I guess that you may need to download it.

You can associate your JUnit with the Eclipse JUnit settings in

```
Windows->Preferences->Java->Build Path->User Libraries
```

Select JUnit there, and you can add and edit JARs.